# How do I see what a MySQL view is made of?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this is easy to do, but I can't find how to do it!  How do I see what a view in MySQL is made of?  Basically, how do I see what statements were used in the original CREATE VIEW?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's more likely to be slugs and snails and puppy dog tails.

Comment: I fear you're probably right. :) (What, that comment was offensive-voted away by three users? Seriously?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See the documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-view.html) on `SHOW CREATE VIEW`

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname;
```

And actually, I usually use `\G` to suppress tabular output for easier reading:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname\G
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW
```